# Ensure weak connectivity in all k-out k-regular graphs depending on the number of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

When generating a random k-out k-regular directed graph, each node chooses randomly a distinct set of k nodes and creates k out-edges to them.

I've only found results to my first question where $P = 1$ when $n \to \infty$ **whp**, where we find an asymptotic threshold for $k$.
But I'm interested in a fixed and **small** number $n$, and I'm interested in a **100% probability** to generate a connected graph in the end.

- If I know the number of total nodes (let's say $n=10$). What is the minimum $k$ so that the graph will have 100% of probability to stay weakly connected?
- Do we have a simple formula if I add a constraint on the vertex-connectivity? If I want to add the constraint that the graph should have a 2-connectivity, i.e. I can lose at most one node without disconnecting the graph, what is the minimum $k$ (number of distinct neighbors chosen randomly) ensuring 100% probability to generate that?

Comment: It's not really a question about the random process if you want a $100\%$ probability of getting something. It's a question about the minimum $k$ for which *all* $k$-out graphs have the property.

Comment: Title updated! That's maybe one of the reasons I wasn't finding the answer anywhere. I was thinking I need the "random graphs" concept. I was tricked by the fact that I'm indeed randomly choosing the neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph were *not* weakly connected, there would have to be a connected component with at most $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$ nodes. (If all components were larger than this, then since we have at least $2$ components, we'd end up with more than $n$ nodes total.)

In this component, each node can have edges to at most $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor - 1$ other nodes, so this can only happen (but can still happen!) when $k \le \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor - 1$.

When $k \ge \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$, the graph is guaranteed to be weakly connected.

---

For the $2$-connected graph, I am assuming you still want weak connectivity. Here, suppose the graph is *not* $2$-connected: deleting some node $v$ disconnects the graph. Then $G-v$ has $n-1$ nodes, so there is a connected component with at most $\lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \rfloor$ nodes.

A node in that component of $G-v$ can have edges to at most $\lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \rfloor - 1$ other nodes in that component, but it can also have an edge to $v$. This can still happen when $k = \lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \rfloor$.

When $k \ge \lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \rfloor + 1$, the graph is guaranteed to be $2$-connected.

Similarly, when $k \ge \lfloor \frac {n-c+1}2 \rfloor + c -1$, the graph is guaranteed to be $c$-connected.

Comment: Thanks very much!
I'm just struggling to understand why there would have to be a connected component with at most floor(n/2) nodes, if the graph were *not weakly* connected.

Comment: I've added a sentence about it. The intuition is that we're always going to pick the smallest component there is to look at - so the worst case for us is that there's only two components, and they're both about half of the graph.